# INSERT INTO error in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
Notice: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
        check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
        version for the right syntax to use near 
'usage VALUES('16','143','ew','weff','25-3-2010','8.00 AM','22-3-2010','10.00 AM''

at line 1 in:

INSERT INTO usage 
VALUES('16'
      ,'143'
      ,'ew'
      ,'weff'
      ,'25-3-2010'
      ,'8.00 AM'
      ,'22-3-2010'
      ,'10.00 AM'
      ,'wfsdc'
      , '34'
      ,' frsdfr '
      ,'TEST 1'
      ,'ISMAIL SALLEH'
      ,'efsdc'
  )
```

I've no idea where is the error... I'm staring on this for 2 hours, but really cannot find the error.

Comment: -1 We're programmers too, not magicians.  It is impossible to tell what the problem could be just based on that SQL.  We need to see the table design, and a sample record would be helpful too.

Comment: Please post the structure for that table.  Are you missing a field?

Comment: i've check all the table field..there no missing field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO `usage` VALUES ....
```

You simply need to [wrap the table name in backticks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html), because `USAGE` is a reserved word in MySQL.

Source: [MySQL Docs: Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: when i run at sql..the error become near 'usage VALUES('16','143','ew','weff','25-3-2010','8.00 AM','22-3-2010','10.00 AM'' i dont know to solve it...i 've compare to the other code...but it look similar...

Comment: wrap the table name in backticks, not quotes.
INSERT INTO ``usage`` (not 'usage')

Comment: ok..it almost done..it the new error occurs 
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in INSERT INTO `usage` VALUES('16','143','ew','weff','25-3-2010','8.00 AM','22-3-2010','10.00 AM','wfsdc', '34',' frsdfr ','TEST 1','ISMAIL
what is the coloums count?

Comment: thanks daniel...the error because there where 'status' field in the table...is it possible if i want to insert data into table with 1 field without  data..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried retyping it from scratch in case you put the line together using cut and paste and maybe accidentally included an invisible control character which makes the SQL parser choke...?

Comment: i also think like that...but i've 2time retyping it...and really2 mess with this...